# removing index.php IIS 7.5 webconfig

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, iis

I would like to remove index.php from my permalink.
I am using Codeigniter website.
I have passed the requirements to use pretty permalink:
**-PHP Version 5.4.27 Codeigniter 

-IIS 7.5

-URL Rewrite 2.0

-Server API: FAST CGI**

Before, I have removed index.php from codeigniter. 
I wonder if wordpress webconfig  file has conflicted with codeigniter.
Some help on determining the right webconfig  would be greatly appreciated!

```
website.com/en/user => codeigniter with the controller User
website.com/blog

/apps
/system
/blog
```

web config to remove CI index.php

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>   
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>

    </rules>
    </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

/blog => WP app

web.config on WP dir

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The same question on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074588/wordpress-pretty-permalink-404-error-installed-on-iis-7-5

Comment: Similar Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439087/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-on-windows-server-and-iis/38524169#38524169 Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524169/6614080
may work for those who are struggling.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for a while in the web.config structure. I found out we need to clear the rule before to add another rule. Just add tag `</clear>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <clear/>
    <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make web.config put in the root directory.

User code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
     <system.webServer>

     <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
      <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

   <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
   </rules>
   </rewrite>

 </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 <compilation debug="true"/>
 </system.web>
```