# Remove index.php from url in permalinks over IIS server (web.config)

Tags: permalinks, iis

I have a WP installation in its own folder (*my-domain.com/site*) and I'm trying that site works over *my-domain.com*. I'm not moving the installation files, actually I'm just [giving to WP its own directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

The WP installation is running over an **IIS server**. So I have a **web.config** file.

I've already done the steps that Wordpress Codex says:

1. Change the site address to *my-domain.com*.
2. Copy (not move) the *index.php* and MOVE the *web.config*, both to root directory.
3. In *index.php* (root directory) I've changed this line: `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/site/wp-blog-header.php' );`

According [WP Codex for Permalinks without mod_rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite), in the permalinks settings (in dashboard) I set to: `/index.php/%postname%/`. If I remove the `index.php` part from the permalinks settings doesn't work anymore.

Right now my permalinks are working, but in this way: *my-domain.com/index.php/page_example*. I want to remove the "/index.php/" part from the url.

In my **web.config** I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've tried even add a `<clear/>` [before add the rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181509/removing-index-php-iis-7-5-webconfig) but without success.

**Note:** If I left the site address (URL) with: *my-domain.com/site* and remove the "/index.php/" part from permalinks settings, the permalinks works good like this: *my-domain.com/page_example*.

Any idea how to solve this? Maybe I'm missing some rules in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

There was something installed on the IIS server that was capable to read the `.htaccess` files; and was ignoring the `web.config` so the [WP documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Moving_a_Root_install_to_its_own_directory) with `.htaccess` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below in your web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
     </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```